# Simple RegEx Example

Tags: c#, regex

I'm horrible at regex so please bear with me here:

I need to a match where the first character can be anything and the next two have to be RS.

so...

XRS123445 - Match

Comment: Then don't use regex.

Comment: Poor style of asking question

Comment: @azhar_SE_nextbridge Yet 2 upvotes... :\

Comment: @azhar_SE_nextbridge it is not a question, OP is asking for code :)

Comment: @DanielKelley 1 by me unconciously :(

Comment: What have you tried? If you show some effort, you won't get downvoted and will get better quality help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex you're looking for:

```
^.RS.*
```

This would match on any of these:

- XRS123445
- 4RSabc
- YRS

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you start reading [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). Matching any character at a position is basically the simplest thing you can do with regular expressions. There are many different things you can use too:

- Any alphanumeric character(\w)
- Any character whatsoever(.)
- A range of characters ([A-Z])
- Any character in a certain unicode range ([\uxxx-\uxxx])

and more. You should also be careful as certain regex languages have ceratin nuances and certain flags have to be set to get the same result. I wouldn't get into more detail to avoid confusion here.

Answer (score 1):

```
.RS.*
```

Should match as . means any character and then RS as per your requirements

Comment: He also suggests that he wants any characters after the RS part

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to finish my statement

Comment: @Marco , have a look at http://regexone.com/ they have a basic tutorial you can follow.

Comment: Link the tutorial as part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern

```
var pattern = "^.RS";
```